# checkout Selected files using batch file from Tortoise SVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, svn-checkout

i wan't to check only the selected files from the SVN instead of checkout entire GB'd of data using batch files .. those files may be in different folders .

Answer (score 0):

1. You can't checkout single file, less possible SOURCE URL is only parent folder of file
2. You can `svn cat` any file from repository-URL and redirect output into local file, but this file will be:

   - Unversioned data
   - Unrelated to repository

Comment: @user229022 - yes, you can export dirs

Comment: thanks lazy .. but i don't need to click ok many times on that dialog box.. i need to check out 20 folders , so i can't click 20 times ok on svn dialog box...  is there any way out... i checked drop export but i  failed to export itself..

Comment: @user229022 - interactive *by design* GUI-tools can be only poorly used as automation-tools. Write 20 strings of `svn export` for CLI-client inside one bat-file

Comment: thats what even i have done, but even in export , dialog box will appear 20 time... :(

Comment: @user229022 - dialog box in CLI svn?! Don't fool me